# Set the first of the month of a NSDate

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I'm using a NSDate that is incremented/decremented thanks to NSDateCompoments:

```
dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    self.date = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
```

...

```
[dateComponents setDay:1];
                    self.date = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:self.date options:0];
                    [dateComponents setDay:0];
```

Now, I want to set the day to set the NSDate to the first of the month (and the first month of the year too), but I dont know how to do

Thanks a lot!!!

**EDIT:**

```
 NSDateComponents *dateComponentsSetFirst = [gregorian components:( NSYearCalendarUnit |
                                                              NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit ) fromDate:self.date];

    switch (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            requestTy = @"hours";
            break;
        case 1:
            requestTy = @"days";
            NSLog (@"avant %@",self.date);
            [dateComponents setDay:1];
            self.date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:dateComponentsSetFirst];
            [dateComponents setDay:0];
            NSLog (@"après %@",self.date);
            break;
        case 2:
            requestTy = @"months";
            NSLog (@"before %@",self.date);
            [dateComponents setMonth:1];
            self.date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:dateComponentsSetFirst];
            [dateComponents setMonth:0];
            NSLog (@"after : %@",self.date);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

give me

```
2011-08-17 11:23:34.365 e-mars[20942:207] avant 2011-08-17 09:23:30 GMT
2011-08-17 11:23:34.366 e-mars[20942:207] après 2011-08-16 22:00:00 GMT
```

when I pass in the case 1 !

and

```
2011-08-17 11:26:05.747 e-mars[20942:207] before 2011-08-16 22:00:00 GMT
2011-08-17 11:26:05.747 e-mars[20942:207] after : 2011-08-16 22:00:00 GMT
```

when I pass in the case 2 !

Comment: replace `[dateComponents setDay:1]` with `[dateComponentsSetFirst setDay:1]`

Comment: hum .... stuuupid ;-) I tried to use the old date component...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not adding components to a date. You simply initialize the dateComponents from a given  date, set the day and month (and year if you want) and then get the dateFromComponents.
[Apple Date and Time Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000039i)

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components:( NSYearCalendarUnit |
NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit ) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[dateComponents setDay:1];
[dateComponents setMonth:1];
self.date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
```

Comment: apparently, it doesn't work :'( it puts me on the december 1901 ... ^^

Comment: Did you initialize the dateComponents from a date?

Comment: I've edited my first post. self.date is the date. Now, the lines I've put isn't working apparently... the date isn't set to the first

Comment: I think it looks fine. NSLog self.date after you assigned it the new value. Why do you set the day of dateComponents to 0 after dateFromComponents?