# How to get actual first day of the month, possible with my time zone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nscalendar

I'm trying to get the first day of the month, but I'm getting the UTC value. I think I need my locale date instead?

[image]

Comment: `NSDate` is always in UTC. If you want to get a string with other timezone here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592556/objective-c-how-can-i-get-the-current-date-in-utc-timezone

Comment: @Artrmz thanks for your comment, I really need this as a date. Not sure what to do here anyway.

Comment: What do you need that for? It shows you date which is 1 hour earlier than first day of the month because you probably live in the +1 time zone. Once you run it on device it should show correct date in the calendar.

Comment: @Artrmz my time zone is British Summer Time in the simulator, surely this will be the same in my device and users devices (reflecting their time zones) too? I'm using it to select a specific day, either today or a selected day in a calendar control (in this case the first day of the month when I navigation to a new month page). So the correct day number is important. Thanks again.

Comment: BST (British Summer Time) equals UTC +1. That would explain the 1 hour difference but I don't know why it's actually 1 month off. Anyway here is similiar question, maybe it'll help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089720/set-the-first-of-the-month-of-a-nsdate

Comment: @Artrmz its' the correct month may - 5

Comment: @Artrmz looking at that example, I have to re-set the month too? seems odd

Comment: It's correct month but last day of the month, once you add the timezone difference it would be 1st of June.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried this myself:

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components:( NSYearCalendarUnit |
                                                          NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit ) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[dateComponents setDay:1];
NSLog(@"%@", [gregorian dateFromComponents:dateComponents]);
```

And it properly prints `2015-04-30 22:00:00 +0000` which would be 1st of May after adding 2 hour (in my case) timezone difference. Just re-check your code, seems like `self.calender.currentDate` gives wrong month?

Comment: it was another issue.